# Grammar with Gate ANNIE

Tags: java, grammar, gate

Hello I have been trying to work on information retrieval for quite sometime and have been facing some difficulties. 
Recently I downloaded StandAloneAnnie.java from following link

http://gate.ac.uk/wiki/code-repository/src/sheffield/examples/StandAloneAnnie.java
Though I have been able to execute it and see the output I have a query or two.

1. This program annotates people and locations, where is the grammar stored for annotating such entities.
2. How can I write my own simple grammar to extract some data and use it in my copy of StandAloneAnnie.java?

Previous posts
[Hundreds of RegEx on one string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022379/hundreds-of-regex-on-one-string) [New to NLP, Question about annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310303/new-to-nlp-question-about-annotation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following is a simple grammar for tagging Height of a person

```
Phase: Meaurements
Input: Token Number 
Options: control=appelt debug=true



Rule: Height
(
({Number})
( {Token.string=~"[Ff]t"} | {Token.string=~"[Ii]n"} | {Token.string=~"[Cc]m"})
):height
-->
:height.Height= {value= :height.Number.value, unit= :height.Token.string}
```

This is the main code that gets executed,

```
    public static void main(String arg[]) {

            Gate.init();
            gate.Corpus corpus= (Corpus) Factory.createResource("gate.corpora.CorpusImpl");

//You need to register the plugin before you load it.

            Gate.getCreoleRegister().registerDirectories(new File(Gate.getPluginsHome(), ANNIEConstants.PLUGIN_DIR).toURI().toURL());
            Gate.getCreoleRegister().registerDirectories(new URL("file:///GATE_HOME/plugins/Tagger_Numbers"));//change this path


            Document doc = new DocumentImpl();
//The string to be annotated.

String str = "Height is 60 in. Weight is 150 lbs pulse rate 90 Pulse rate 90";
DocumentContentImpl impl = new DocumentContentImpl(str);
doc.setContent(impl);

//Loading processing resources. refer http://gate.ac.uk/gate/doc/plugins.html for what class the plugin belongs to

            ProcessingResource token = (ProcessingResource) Factory.createResource("gate.creole.tokeniser.DefaultTokeniser", Factory.newFeatureMap());
            ProcessingResource sspliter = (ProcessingResource) Factory.createResource("gate.creole.splitter.SentenceSplitter", Factory.newFeatureMap());
            ProcessingResource number = (ProcessingResource) Factory.createResource("gate.creole.numbers.NumbersTagger", Factory.newFeatureMap());


/*pipeline is an application that needs to be created to use resources loaded above.
Reasources must be added in a particular order eg. below the 'number' resource requires the document to be tokenised. */

corpus.add(doc);
SerialAnalyserController pipeline = (SerialAnalyserController) Factory.createResource("gate.creole.SerialAnalyserController", Factory.newFeatureMap(), Factory.newFeatureMap(), "ANNIE");
pipeline.setCorpus(corpus);
pipeline.add(token);
pipeline.add(sspliter);
pipeline.add(number);
pipeline.execute();

//Extract info from an annotated document.

AnnotationSetImpl ann=(AnnotationSetImpl)doc.getAnnotations();
Iterator<Annotation>i = ann.get(vital).iterator();
Annotation annotation = i.next();
long start = annotation.getStartNode().getOffset();
long end =  annotation.getEndNode().getOffset();
System.out.println(doc.toString().substring((int)start, (int)end));

}
```

Note:-
In the above code, the grammar for Height will be written in a .jape file. You need to run this grammar using a JAPE(JAPE Plus) transducer. We just need to execute the application('pipeline') in our main code. You can find tutorial for writing jape at gate.ac.uk/sale/tao

Comment: Shouldn't the 'extract info from annotated document' part of code be with a `while` loop?

Answer (score 0):

There is an [Introduction to Annie](http://gate.ac.uk/sale/talks/annie-tutorial.ppt) powerpoint which explains how the grammar is stored.  They are in [Jape](http://gate.ac.uk/wiki/jape-repository/) files.

Comment: This still doesn't show how can I use it in my own java program.